CMake `find_package` in module mode that does not use the `CMake` built-in find modules
For a project that will be supporting self-contained builds, I need to be able to call find_package in a way that can use project-supplied find modules but not the default built-in CMake find modules.
I don't want it to pick system-installed libraries but I need the flexibility of find modules - which allow me for example to use find_package(JPEG) and to get either libjpeg or libjpeg-turbo depending on the environment. I know that in theory this can be accomplished by well-crafted config files too, but I am using conan and conan delivers find modules for some packages that can have multiple install candidates.
This is possible for config files, but I don't see any way to do it for find modules.
Is it possible?

Just add path to your Find<Foo>.cmake script to CMAKE_MODULE_PATH variable.

This will allow me to use the Find<Foo>.cmake module - this is not a problem. I won't to prevent CMake from using its built-in default find modules - even when I do not have a replacement module.

If you don't have Find<Foo>.cmake module, and do not want to use one shipped with CMake, then the only way for find_package to succeed is to find a config file. In that case just use CONFIG keyword for your find_package call. I don't understand your problem.

Yes, but in this case I cannot use it if I have it. I would like to continue to be using my own find modules - but not those supplied by the system. These modules are optional - they may come from conan which may supply custom find modules.
